# How to check if the difference between 2 dates is more than 20 minutes

Tags: java, date

I have a datetime  in a variable `previous`. Now i want to check if the previous datetime is more than twenty minutes before the current time.

```
Date previous = myobj.getPreviousDate();

Date now = new Date();

//check if previous was before 20 minutes from now ie now-previous >=20
```

How can we do it?

Comment: What form of time do these functions return? Unix Time?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use

```
if (now.getTime() - previous.getTime() >= 20*60*1000) {
    ...
}
```

Or, more verbose, but perhaps slightly easier to read:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

...

long MAX_DURATION = MILLISECONDS.convert(20, MINUTES);

long duration = now.getTime() - previous.getTime();

if (duration >= MAX_DURATION) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @all:isnt if now.getTime -previous.getTime > 20*60*1000.I want to check if previous time was more then 20 min in past from now

Comment: Right, if "now minus previous" is greater than 20 minutes, then previous took place more than 20 minutes ago.

Comment: This does not work when the 2 times overlap the Daylight savings switch point.

Answer (score 22):

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
boolean result = Minutes.minutesBetween(new DateTime(previous), new DateTime())
                        .isGreaterThan(Minutes.minutes(20));
```

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 solution:

```
private static boolean isAtleastTwentyMinutesAgo(Date date) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
    Instant twentyMinutesAgo = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(20));

    try {
        return instant.isBefore(twentyMinutesAgo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works in Java 6 & 7 too with ThreeTen-Backport project, and in Android with ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 6):

You should really use Calendar object instead of Date:

```
Calendar previous = Calendar.getInstance();
previous.setTime(myobj.getPreviousDate());
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - previous.getTimeInMillis();
if(diff >= 20 * 60 * 1000)
{
    //at least 20 minutes difference
}
```

Comment: Should be `long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - previous.getTimeInMillis();`

Comment: This does not work when the 2 times overlap the Daylight savings switch point.

Comment: To ignore the power saving point you would need to work with UTC times. Or if you are lucky the country where the applications is running has no Daylight saving switch point (e.g. China)

Answer (score 1):

Get the times in milliseconds, and check the difference:

```
long diff = now.getTime() - previous.getTime();
if (diff > 20L * 60 * 1000) {
    // ...
}
```

Another solution could be to use Joda time.

Comment: The OP asks to check if `previuos` is before 20 mins from `now`, not the difference between them

Comment: @Eng: Read to fast. Corrected :)

Comment: is the comparrison sign used in oposite way. i want to check if previous time was more then 20 min in past from crrent time

Comment: @Akshay: The comparison sign is fine. The substraction was in the wrong direction (now corrected). But if ``previous`` is 20 minutes before ``now``, the time difference will be greater than 20 minutes.